# How to use IdentityServer3 with asp.net identity database

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver3

I am following this link https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html and successfully created a standalone IdentityServer and able use it and authenticate my mvc and web api apps.

But to go further I want to integrate my asp.net identity database with Identity server and get users and roles from database. Can someone please help me this as I am not able to relevant docs on IdentityServer3 documents.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using IdentityServer3 instead of IdentityServer4 (for what seems like a new project)? IS4's documentation has a section all about integration with ASP.NET Identity, btw: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/aspnet_identity.html

Comment: @Dai every example of IS4 is with .net core and I am trying to integrate in my MVC5 app.